# PECL bbcode package fails to build

Tags: php, debian, bbcode, pecl

I was running PHP5.3 on Debian Squeeze and the install went fine. I upgraded to PHP5.4 using the dotdeb repository and discovered bbcode functions no longer worked. I then tried to reinstall:

```
pecl uninstall bbcode
pecl install bbcode
```

however it's returning the following:

```
/tmp/pear/temp/bbcode/php_bbcode.c:38: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘bbcode_functions’
/tmp/pear/temp/bbcode/php_bbcode.c:65: error: ‘bbcode_functions’ undeclared here (not in a function)
make: *** [php_bbcode.lo] Error 1
```

I have php5-dev, build-essential and ubuntu-dev-tools installed already. Full result below:

```
# pecl install bbcode
downloading bbcode-1.0.2.tgz ...
Starting to download bbcode-1.0.2.tgz (46,961 bytes)
.............done: 46,961 bytes
7 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root30VR7V/bbcode-1.0.2
running: /tmp/pear/temp/bbcode/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20100525
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... 0.13.5 (ok)
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking whether to enable C based BBCode support... yes, shared
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root30VR7V/bbcode-1.0.2/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/tmp/pear/temp/bbcode/lib -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/bbcode -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root30VR7V/bbcode-1.0.2/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root30VR7V/bbcode-1.0.2/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/bbcode -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/bbcode/php_bbcode.c -o php_bbcode.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I/tmp/pear/temp/bbcode/lib -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/bbcode -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root30VR7V/bbcode-1.0.2/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root30VR7V/bbcode-1.0.2/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/bbcode -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/bbcode/php_bbcode.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_bbcode.o
/tmp/pear/temp/bbcode/php_bbcode.c:38: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘bbcode_functions’
/tmp/pear/temp/bbcode/php_bbcode.c:65: error: ‘bbcode_functions’ undeclared here (not in a function)
make: *** [php_bbcode.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Answer (score 10):

Try installing 1.0.3b1 version. That should compile fine with PHP 5.4.

```
pecl install bbcode-1.0.3b1
```

Comment: Also remember to `chmod 755 /usr/lib64/php/modules/bbcode.so` otherwise php will say "Unable to load dynamic library... cannot open shared object file" (at least mine did)